# Creating complex model from a basic table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm not really sure how to phrase this question. Basically I have a table in my database like so:

```
 Table1
 _________
|id       |
|_________|
|services |
|_________|
|solutions|
|_________|
```

but in my model I'm trying to map it to three objects:

```
class studies
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public List<Service> services {get;set;}
    public List<Solution> solutions {get;set;}
}

class Solution
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string description {get;set;}
}

class Service
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string description {get;set;}
}
```

So what I need to do is pull down all the table data from the database and then re-assign it to my classes. How would I do something like this? I am working under constraints in which not allowed to alter the table structure, so just re-designing the database is not an option.

Comment: In the database, is "services" comma separated list of services stored in 1 field per record?

Comment: What are the IDs in Solution and Service classes? Same IDs from studies class?

Comment: @mbeckish yes. it will typically be something like service1,service2,service3. I need to separate those out so that there is an object for each of them, and not duplicates.

Comment: Also the IDs are unique to services and solutions, they are used because I will need to return lists of just the services or solutions.

Comment: Can you give more details on how you plan on using these classes? How would you ensure same Service, or Solution always gets the same ID?

Comment: @Floremin They will be used to return a specific study or studies based on filters (like a particular solution + service), or to return a list of services in the database, or a list of solutions.

Comment: Like a user might ask to see all solutions, and then find all studies that contain a solution ID of 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would retrieve the data from DB in a collection of Study objects:

```
class Study 
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Solutions {get; set;}
    public string Services {get; set;}
}
```

Then I'd have to loop through the collection and parse Solutions and Services strings for each assembling two dictionaries "Solutions" and "Services" where the keys would be names of each solution and service respectively and values would be lists of associated services (for a solution key) or associated solutions (for a service key). Something like:

```
var solutions = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
var services = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

Not sure if the syntax is correct, but you get the idea. While populating the dictionaries make sure you don't insert duplicate values in lists of solutions/services for any particular key.

Then, looking up a list of available solutions for a "service1" would be something like:

```
var service1Solutions = services["service1"];
```

Comment: Thank you for your h elp, this pointed me in the right direction. Everything is falling together nicely now.